# Validating token with jwks

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I am trying to setup Kong on a GKE cluster so that I can validate the incoming requests. I have a jwks file/uri that I would like to use for validation.

I have followed following steps...

1. Deploy a hello world app exposed via a service.
2. Install Kong
   `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/master/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml`
3. Setup Kong JWT plugin

   ```
   apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
   kind: KongPlugin
   metadata:
     name: weather-jwt
     namespace: weather-api
   plugin: jwt
   ```
4. Create an ingress

   ```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: weather-ingress
     namespace: weather-api
     annotations:          
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
       plugins.konghq.com: weather-jwt
     spec:
       backend:
         serviceName: weather-service
         servicePort: 80
   ```

Next step I see are..

1. Create a secret that has the public key something like

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   metadata:
     name: apiuser-apikey
     namespace: weather-api
   type: Opaque
   stringData:
     kongCredType: jwt
     key: https://farrellsoft.auth0.com/
     algorithm: RS256
     rsa_public_key: |-
   -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
   MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA3PYgeiVyURLhqAkkUOfL
   roY281upGVWgBTZKZu6rIMPCiyzuZU8Rnlc1k+cHkbov0uRZIVmwrhMLTr6E9ZwD
   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
   ```
2. Create kong consumer

   ```
   apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
   kind: KongConsumer
   metadata:
     name: api-consumer
     namespace: weather-api
   username: apiUser
   credentials:
     - apiuser-apikey
   ```

This should all work fine... The problem is that I don't have the public key for the secret. All I have is the JWKS uri something like `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/jwks.json` and m not sure how to use it for token validation. Is there any other plugin that I need to use.

Comment: are you using kong open source or enterprise? which version (1, 2, 2.2 and so on) of kong are you using?

Comment: @MarceloBezerra m using opensource kong & kong:2.2 as per the dbless manifest